# How can I generate pairs of users from list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, shuffle

I am trying to create a function which generates pairs of users from list. Everyone have to get a pair.
Example list of user IDs:

```
list = [123, 456, 789]
...smth...
result =  {123:456, 456:789, 789:123} — OK
```

```
list = [123, 456, 789]
...smth...
result =  {123:456, 456:123, 789:789} — BAD
```

```
list = [123, 456, 789, 234, 678]
...smth...
result = {123:456, 456:123, xxxxx} - BAD
```

Trying to do this in Python but can't find a solution.

Tried lists, sets, dicts, but cant find an algorithm.

Comment: Can you post an example of the code you've tried so far?

Comment: all my code got errors :(

Comment: But what have you tried so far? What errors do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pairs will be consecutive. I.e. first item with the second, second with the third, and so on, until the last item pairs with the first, and you're showing in your example a dictionary structure, so maybe you can use a function like this.

```
def make_pairs(input_list):
    out_dict = dict()  # output dictionary
    for i in range(len(input_list)):  # i is from 0 to len(list) - 1
        # if i is not pointing to the last item
        if not i == len(input_list) - 1:
            # make pair from the i-th item and the (i+1) item
            out_dict[input_list[i]] = input_list[i+1]
        # i points to the last item
        else:
            # make pair from the last item and the first item
            out_dict[input_list[i]] = input_list[0]
    return out_dict

input_list = [123, 456, 789]
out_dict = make_pairs(input_list)
print(out_dict)
```

Of course, this is somewhat of a bad solution. For example, if the list has repeating items, then keys will overwrite each other.

As mentioned above, avoid using `list` as a variable name, it's a reserved Python keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the pairs to be tuples, you can use [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

From the docs (table on top of the page):

> r-length tuples, in sorted order, no repeated elements

[And](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

> Elements are treated as unique based on their position, not on their value. So if the input elements are unique, there will be no repeated values in each combination.

So:

```
from itertools import combinations

data = [123, 456, 789, 234, 678]

result = list(combinations(data, 2))
# [(123, 456), (123, 789), (123, 234), (123, 678), (456, 789), (456, 234), (456, 678), (789, 234), (789, 678), (234, 678)]
```

Also, avoid using the "`list`" word for naming, as [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) is a Python container.